# "if diminishing" in the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

"In the common law provinces(in other words, all provinces except Quebec) and in the territories, judge-made rules play an important if diminishing role in the whole body of the law."

what does " if dinimishing" means in this sentence? I guessed it is a grammar mistake.

Comment: Breaking up the sentence: *"... an important, but diminishing, role..."* It means that the role of judges developing the (common) law is important, but becoming less so. Presumably because "the whole body of the law" is becoming statutory (enacted by statute).

Comment: Please copy and paste the meaning of diminishing from a dictionary.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you please explain why "if" acts as "but" in this sentence? Why do people chose "if" over but in such sentences?

Comment: Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/if) meaning **7** with example *the new leaders have little if any control* and others.

Comment: *Those rules play an important role **even if we must admit that it's a diminishing role***. You'll also see the same usage *negated*, to "tentatively" advance some possibility that might actually be a bit of an exaggeration. *Large family gatherings are unwise **if not reckless** while the pandemic continues to rage*.